# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined value.Title[0]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have 3 statements like so:

```
  if (value.Title) { caption = value.Title; return; }
  if (value.Title[0]) { caption = value.Title[0]; return; }
  if (value.titleHTML5) { caption = value.titleHTML5; return; }
```

if `value.Title` `undefined` then it goes to 2nd if statement. But if `value.Title[0]` `undefined` then it gives run time exception. Why it doesn't go to 3rd if statement?

*Exception:*

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

**Note:** I'm reading different nodes here. It has different properties on each node like so. Some node has `Title` some has `Title[0]` and etc. i.e. I don't have both `Title` and `Title[0]` on the same node. That was the issue here. Problem is on `18` node.

```
"17": {
      "class": "ScrollView",
      "Title": "Guest Services",
      "Subtitle": "",
 "18": {
      "class": "Service",
      "title": "calendar",
      "imageHTML5": "",
      "titleHTML5": "Why you",
    },
"19": {
        "class": "FinalView",
        "Title": [
            "My Club"
          ],
        "Subtitle": "",
```

Comment: your second if statement doesn't make any sense

Comment: How to make it more sense? @PranavCBalan

Comment: `if (value.Title) { if(typeof value.Title === 'string') { caption = value.Title; return; }
  if (value.Title[0]) { caption = value.Title[0]; return; } }`

Comment: @PranavCBalan This is not what I need. Please see my post again

Comment: You comment on every awnser that this is not what you need. Then you should make it more clear what it is that you want

Comment: I have done that. Please see it @Wendelin

Comment: Your question is 'Why it doesn't go to 3rd if statement?' That question has been awnsered multiple times

Comment: Please read the `Note` section. I don't have both Title and Title[0] on the same node. That was the issue here. @Wendelin

Comment: "19": {
        "class": "FinalView",
        "Title": [
            "My Club"
          ],
        "Subtitle": ""
}
If this is your node than value.Title == true even if it is an array. So all of the answers do work

Comment: @Wendelin Problem is on `"18":` node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `value.Title` is undefined and you trying to do this `if (undefined[0]) {...}`

Add check to your if statement, like this.

```
if (value.Title && value.Title[0]) { caption = value.Title[0]; return; }
```

**UPDATE**

You can use `object.hasOwnProperty()` to check whether or not object contains specific property. Then to correctly recognize array I suggest you to use `Array.isArray()` method.

Check out full working expample with your supplied data structure below.

```js
const data = {
  "17": {
    "class": "ScrollView",
    "Title": "Guest Services",
    "Subtitle": "",
  },
  "18": {
    "class": "Service",
    "title": "calendar",
    "imageHTML5": "",
    "titleHTML5": "Why you",
  },
  "19": {
    "class": "FinalView",
    "Title": [
        "My Club"
      ],
    "Subtitle": "",
  },
  "20": {
    "class": "Foo",
    "Subtitle": "Bar",
  }
}

const res = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [ key, value ]) => {
  let caption = 'Default caption'
  
  if (value.hasOwnProperty('Title')) {
    caption = Array.isArray(value.Title) ? value.Title[0] : value.Title
  } else if (value.hasOwnProperty('titleHTML5')) {
    caption = value.titleHTML5
  }
  
  return {
    ...acc,
    [key]: caption,
  }
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: This is not what I need. Please see my post again.

Comment: @Sampath Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

As you saied it throws a runtime exception when value.Title is undefined.
The execution of a script is stopped after a runtime exception an thus your 3rd if statement never gets evaluated.

To make sure that this doesn't happen you could rewrite your code like this:

```
if (value.Title) { 
    caption = value.Title;
    if (value.Title[0]) { 
        caption = value.Title[0];
    }
    return;
}
if (value.titleHTML5) { caption = value.titleHTML5; return; }
```

Comment: This is not what I need. Please see my post again

Comment: Are your sure? You want to find the title in the JSON. In that case my code does exactly what you want. If that's not what you want to do then you should update your question and make it more clear

Comment: I have updated it. I have to read distinct nodes with different properties. Please see it.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (value.Title) { caption = value.Title; return; }
```

this means that if this statement fails the next if should be run, which is

```
if (value.Title[0]) { caption = value.Title[0]; return; }
```

but remember if we get to this point, it means `value.title = undefined`, but then you still try to access the element at 0 of a value that's already undefined. The solution is to do both checks

```
if (value.Title && value.Title[0]) { caption = value.Title[0]; return; }
```

Comment: This is not what I need. Please see my post again

Answer (score 0):

If it's not undefined caption will get the value.Tittle and the method will return. If it's undefined you will try to read the first position of undefined, which makes no sense at all and of course will raise an exception. That will never reach 3rd statement because will stop on first when it's defined or  ll raise an exception if it is.

Anyways you're coding in the wrong way.

Comment: This is not what I need. Please see my post again